# Cannot decrypt files on a Mac using openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, macos, cryptography

This is the command I used to encrypt the files on my Mac around 2017.  I don't know if my Mac was running High Sierra at the time or not, because I am usually late to the party when it comes to updates until I absolutely have to do so.

I was able to decrypt these files in 2018, but for some reason I cannot do so anymore.

```
tar cz folder_to_encrypt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e > out.tar.gz.enc
```

This is what I use to decrypt it now, using the same computer running Catalina

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in out.tar.gz.enc | tar xz
```

The error message I get is:

```
bad decrypt
4435975788:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:521:
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

I've read some posts talking about different versions of openssl and digests etc.  I downloaded an old version of of LibreSSL 2.3.6; it still fails but the error code is slightly different (06065064):

```
bad decrypt
4606180972:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/Users/joe/Downloads/temp-libressl/libressl-2.3.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:529:
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem before due to OpenSSL changing it's default digest from MD5 to SHA256 ... You might want start looking into that. https://git.openssl.org/?p=openssl.git;a=commit;h=9e8b6f042749ded556380227c9f2db7ffad9a3aa

Comment: Warning: LibreSSL might not work the same as OpenSSL. Try to find the exact library/app you used to encode the file. In the future you might want to use off-the-shelf tools like 7-zip or WinRAR. WinRAR also provides redundancy for your archives - a **single** bad **bit** (not even a byte) may render your entire compressed file completely **broken and unrecoverable**.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes.  How can I find out what version was used in an old version of a Mac OS?

Comment: @John I tried by adding -md sha256 and it produced the same error

Comment: @Cb32019 after `-aes-256-cbc` try adding `-md md5`

Comment: @John I tried that too.  I had these files encrypted and stored on Google drive.  Then I downloaded them.  Maybe a corrupted file?

Comment: @Cb32019 Corruption is a possibility and difficult to confirm without having a SHA1||MD5 to compare.  Out of curiosity I tested between OpenSSL versions `1.0.2k-fips Jan 2017` (default digest MD5) &  `1.1.1g Apr 2020` using `-aes-256-cbc` and had successful results (using a tar.gz). I would suggest installing an older version of OpenSSL on a virtual machine. (I used CentOS 7.7.1908 (Core)) Other than that I can only suggest checking simple things like your `-pass` phrase etc... Good Luck on getting this figured out and post your solution if you can

Comment: Hi John.  Could you assist with installing an older version on my Mac?  I am an idiot when it comes to these things and don't know what version to get or how to get it properly

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple things that have changed. However, based on John suggestion about MD5, and my own tests, I think you may be fine just adding `-md md5` in the decompression step.

I tested encrypting a file with your command, using openssl 1.0.1t. Then tried decrypting with 1.1.1d. It failed with

> *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
> Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
> bad decrypt
> 130692476720256:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:570:

So, it detected that there was a deprecated key derivation, however was unable to apply it automatically (or it is taking it into account, but there is yet *another* thing that changed). This newer version has a parameter `-md` which is absent in the previous one:

```
   -md digest
       Use the specified digest to create the key from the passphrase.
       The default algorithm is sha-256.
```

Based on John's hint of the usage of md5, I did `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -md md5 -in file`, and it was able to correctly decrypt the contents (although it still produces the above warning about the deprecated key derivation).

Comment: Adding -md md5 didn't work with the current version of openssl. Could you help me with where to and how to install the older version of openssl for my mac?

Comment: @Cb32019 you can download previous openssl versions from https://www.openssl.org/source/old/ Compiling should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: I did that.  Now I am following the instructions for installing on MacOS and it's not working.

Comment: I had encrypted using Blowfish, so `openssl bf -in foo.zip -out foo.asdf`. To decypt I was using `openssl bf -d -in foo.asdf -out foo.zip`, which failed with `error:06FFF064`. But adding `-md md5` did the trick, so `openssl bf -md md5 -d -in foo.asdf -out foo.zip`.